# Обработчик ошибок для части кода

Tags: java, appium

Код, который должен быть в обработчике ошибок:

```
WebElement dynamicElement2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("com.kbl.kbl:id/new_contacts_bar")));
dynamicElement2.click();
driver.findElement(By.id("com.kbl.kbl:id/btn_add")).click();
```

Какой класс ошибки нужно указывать для работы с этим ?

Comment: трудно сказать, в таких случаях, если точно не знаете тип, но очень хотите обработать пишите `catch(Exception e)` 

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov заработало, можешь еще подсказать, допустим он обработал ошибку, как мне будет правильней написать что бы он переходил на другую часть кода ?

Comment: Другая часть кода это какая? Оформите ее в виде метода и вызывайте этот метод в блоке `catch`